# Travis CI error importing module

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

This is the log from TravisCI that gives me a couple of errors:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-480690b1.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-4

Build system information
Build language: python
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

LLVM version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ git clone --depth=50 https://github.com/vkaracic/xblocks.org.git vkaracic/xblocks.org
Cloning into 'vkaracic/xblocks.org'...
remote: Counting objects: 91, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Total 91 (delta 34), reused 65 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (91/91), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd vkaracic/xblocks.org
$ git fetch origin +refs/pull/4/merge:
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 9), reused 7 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.
From https://github.com/vkaracic/xblocks.org
 * branch            refs/pull/4/merge -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD

This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
$ source ~/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
$ pip --version
pip 6.0.7 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
You are using pip version 6.0.7, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting Django==1.8.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.8.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
    100% |################################| 6.2MB 64kB/s 
Collecting djangorestframework==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading djangorestframework-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (576kB)
    100% |################################| 577kB 855kB/s 
Collecting django-nose==1.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading django_nose-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pylint==1.4.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading pylint-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (428kB)
    100% |################################| 430kB 1.4MB/s 
Collecting requests==2.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading requests-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (497kB)
    100% |################################| 499kB 786kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose>=1.2.1 in /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-nose==1.4.2->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting logilab-common>=0.53.0 (from pylint==1.4.4->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading logilab-common-1.1.0.tar.gz (184kB)
    100% |################################| 188kB 1.9MB/s 
Collecting six (from pylint==1.4.4->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid>=1.3.6 (from pylint==1.4.4->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading astroid-1.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (183kB)
    100% |################################| 184kB 2.3MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from logilab-common>=0.53.0->pylint==1.4.4->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Installing collected packages: astroid, six, logilab-common, requests, pylint, django-nose, djangorestframework, Django
  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/astroid/astroid/tests/testdata/python3/data/module.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/astroid/astroid/tests/testdata/python3/data/module2.py



  Running setup.py install for logilab-common
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pytest from 664 to 775
    Skipping installation of /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab/__init__.py (namespace package)
    Installing /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logilab_common-1.1.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth
    changing mode of /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/bin/pytest to 775

/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:4: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (1 == 1, 2 == 2), "no error"
/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:5: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (1 == 1, 2 == 2) #this should generate a warning
/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:7: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (1 == 1, ), "no error"
/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:8: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (1 == 1, )
/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:9: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (1 == 1, 2 == 2, 3 == 5), "no error"
/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_assert_2uple.py:11: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?
  assert (True, 'error msg') #this should generate a warning
  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/abstract_abc_methods.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/abstract_class_instantiated_py2.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/abstract_class_instantiated_py3.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/abstract_method_py2.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/abstract_method_py3.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/class_members_py27.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/class_members_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/no_name_in_module.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/old_style_class_py27.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/raising_non_exception_py3.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/unbalanced_tuple_unpacking_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/undefined_variable_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/yield_outside_func.py ...
    File "/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/functional/yield_outside_func.py", line 2
      yield 1  # [yield-outside-function]


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_bad_exception_context_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_continue_not_in_loop.py ...
    File "/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_continue_not_in_loop.py", line 8
      continue


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_e0108.py ...


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_exec_used_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_keyword_repeat.py ...
    File "/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_keyword_repeat.py", line 8
      function_default_arg(two=5, two=7)


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_kwoa_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_noerror_mcs_attr_access.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_noerror_unused_variable_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_return_outside_func.py ...
    File "/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_return_outside_func.py", line 3
      return


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_return_yield_mix_py_33.py ...


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_syntax_error.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_undefined_metaclass_var_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_unused_import_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_used_before_assignment_py30.py

  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_w0705.py ...
    File "/tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_w0705.py", line 28
      __revision__ += 1


  Compiling /tmp/pip-build-RBVFdk/pylint/pylint/test/input/syntax_error.py ...
  Sorry: IndentationError: expected an indented block (syntax_error.py, line 2)




Successfully installed Django-1.8.7 astroid-1.3.8 django-nose-1.4.2 djangorestframework-3.3.1 logilab-common-1.1.0 pylint-1.4.4 requests-2.8.1 six-1.10.0
$ make quality
pylint --rcfile=pylintrc xblock api
************* Module api.urls
E:  4, 0: No name 'xblocks' in module 'api.views' (no-name-in-module)
E:  4, 0: No name 'scrape' in module 'api.views' (no-name-in-module)
make: *** [quality] Error 2

The command "make quality" exited with 2.
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

The command "python manage.py test" exited with 0.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I'm getting import errors, even though the same tests ran locally do not report those errors. 
Here's my project: https://github.com/vkaracic/xblocks/tree/development

Comment: Where's the import error? Seeing a bunch of slightly weird output from pylint, but that looks fairly normal for it's self-tests and it reports as importing ok

Comment: @palfrey at the end of the file: `************* Module api.urls
E:  4, 0: No name 'xblocks' in module 'api.views' (no-name-in-module)
E:  4, 0: No name 'scrape' in module 'api.views' (no-name-in-module)`

Comment: Uh, https://github.com/vkaracic/xblocks/blob/development/api/views.py does not contain either `xblocks` or `scrape`, so that looks right to me...

Comment: OMG! I'm so blind, didn't see that file there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in short we found (see above comments) a file `api/views.py` which got loaded in preference to the files in api/views/. That got deleted and the problem went away :)

Comment: While this may have fixed the immediate problem with the installation, it's clear that the installer also failed in pre-compiling several of the Python source code files (possibly because they were intended for Python 2 where the indentation was fine, but the code will run on Python 3 where the indentation rules are stricter).